# The flutter project has been configured with flavor

Tags: flutter

The flutter project has been configured with flavor. When I run the project natively from Android, how do I specify the flutter program entry file?

Comment: Are you using flavor package or creating it ?

Answer (score 0):

An example to run a flavor:

`flutter run --flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart`

`--flavor prod` after the --flavor option you need to provide the flavor's name as it is declared.

`-t lib/main_prod.dart` the -t flag is the entry file target.